# Fundamental Drag And Drop In iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, drag-and-drop

I've been considering an app now that implements a drag and drop sort of idiom from maybe a side pane or a drawer, etc.  what I can't wrap my head around are how to keep reference to the objects I drop.  I mean; it would be easy if it was just drop the object, then let it alone, but I want more manipulation after the fact.

My brain just cannot wrap around the concept of creating objects out of thin air to place on the 'canvas', or having preset objects (which I imagine would be limited, cumbersome and awkward) already on the canvas that would then just be activated and manipulated easily, seeing as the references to them are created before the fact (my apologies for the loose term 'reference', I mean something like selecting the object and having it's unique properties recognized or displayed).

There must be something I'm missing.  So, I wonder how one might go about implementing drag and drop with interface and manipulation with the dropped object after the fact or maybe sample code or a link to a git or svn repo?  (something like how MIT's scratch, or Xcode's interface builder might work).

For clarity's sake, I know how to go about fiddling with drag and drop thanks to DragKit, but not about editing 'properties' on the object dropped onto the 'canvas', and I would like there to be a near infinite amount of objects that can be dropped on the canvas, yet a set amount of items in the drawer/side view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to be able to drag objects onto a canvas and then manipulate their properties individually. For instance, you'd drag square views onto the screen and then increase its size or change its color.

In order to do something like that, I would have a NSMutableArray or an NSMutableSet that would hold all of the on canvas objects. Then when any interaction comes, you could either dynamically generate gesture recognizers if the objects are UIViews or a subclass. Then in the target of the gesture recognizer you would use the recognizer.view property.

Or you would have to check which object on the canvas you were currently manipulating. That would be done by iterating through the array and seeing which object equals the one you are touching.

Is there anything that you are trying to do but is not working? Have you written any code in attempt to do this?

Comment: I've just got absolutely NO clue what I'm doing.  DragKit's examples confuse me... your idea is plausible though, it does solve about 1/4th of the question. +1